# GameObjects vibrate when in contact with terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First I would rather know why this is happening then get a fix. Knowing will allow me to learn while cut and paste code won't. (An alternative fix would be very nice and I thank you but this baffles me and I want to know why).

Set Up: 
I have a primitive shape GO (gameobject) spawn above the terrain. This GO has a rigid body and I attach a script to it. Seed.cs this class inherits several functions from another class called body. Once spawned the GO falls and comes into contact with the terrain and this is where the problems happen. The GO can either go through the terrain, get stuck half inside, falls get stuck and then be thrown out of the ground, or if the fall is slow enough just continuously vibrate.

I have tried changing the collision detection to all three different types prior to running the scene on the GO but that had little affect. What I found did work was while the scene was running I could change the collision detection from one option to another and my problem seems to disappear. I can throw this change in the start function of the Body class and it works fine. The actual options for collision detection are irrelevant to fixing the problem it only requires that I change it. From Continuous to Discrete or Discrete to ContinuousDynamic its only the fact that I change it that makes the problem go away.

I'm hoping that someone has an idea as to why this is. I do scale the GO if that helps.

The code might look like spaghetti for this is a recreational programming and also this is my first time ever using Unity.

Bellow is my code. 
SimulationController

```
public class SimulationControler : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject entities;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        entities = GameObject.Find ("Enteties");

        EntityHandler entityHandler = entities.GetComponent<EntityHandler>();
        int id = entityHandler.CreateNewEntity ();

        GameObject Adam = entityHandler.GetEntetity (id);
        Entity AdamEntity = Adam.GetComponent<Entity>();
        AdamEntity.StoreResources (1000, 1000);

        GameObject go = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Body Shapes/Cube", typeof(GameObject)), new Vector3(9, 6, 20), Quaternion.Euler(43, 30, 0));
        go.name = "Apple Tree";
        go.rigidbody.angularDrag = 2;
        go.rigidbody.drag = 2;
        go.rigidbody.mass = 444;
        go.AddComponent<Seed> ();
        Seed goSeed = go.GetComponent<Seed> ();
        goSeed.SetDNA("33493339411953125429875244");
        goSeed.SetEntityID (id);
        goSeed.Growth();
        goSeed.Growth();
        goSeed.Growth();
        goSeed.Growth();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}


public class Seed : Body {
}

using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Body : MonoBehaviour {

    private int timet = 0;

    public int maxtimet = 5;
    public string DNA;
    public int DNAPosition = 0;
    public bool Growing = true;
    public int EntityID;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        this.rigidbody.collisionDetectionMode  = CollisionDetectionMode.ContinuousDynamic;
    }

    public void SetEntityID (int id)
    {
        EntityID = id;
    }

    public void SetDNA(string sDNA)
    {
        this.DNA = sDNA;
    }

    int DNAReader(int Size){

        string tempString = "";
        for (long i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            //Debug.Log(DNA.Length);
            if(DNA.Length>DNAPosition)
            {
                tempString = tempString + this.DNA[DNAPosition];
                DNAPosition += 1;
            }
        }
        if (tempString == "") 
        {
            tempString = "-1";
        }
        Debug.Log (tempString);
        return Int32.Parse(tempString);

    }


    public void Growth()
    {

        GameObject entities = GameObject.Find ("Enteties");;
        EntityHandler EntityHandler = entities.GetComponent<EntityHandler> ();
        GameObject goEntity = EntityHandler.GetEntetity (EntityID);
        Entity entity = goEntity.GetComponent<Entity>();

        int growth;
        Vector3 Scale;
        int DNACode = 0;
        bool found = false;
        while (!found) 
        {
            int Code = DNAReader (3);
            switch (Code) {
            case 111:
                //Debug.Log ("Go Back");
                DNAPosition -= DNAReader (2);
                if(DNAPosition<0)
                {
                    DNAPosition = 0;
                }
                found = true;
                break;

            case 222:
                //Debug.Log ("Go Forward");
                DNAPosition += DNAReader (2);
                if(DNAPosition>this.DNA.Length)
                {
                    this.Growing = false;
                }
                found = true;
                break;

            case 331:
                growth = DNAReader(1);
                bool temp = entity.RequestResources(growth*2,growth);
                if(entity.RequestResources(growth*2,growth))
                {
                    this.rigidbody.mass += growth;
                    Scale = this.transform.localScale;
                    Scale.x += growth;
                    this.transform.localScale = Scale;
                }

                found = true;
                break;

            case 332:
                growth = DNAReader(1);
                if(entity.RequestResources(growth*2,growth))
                {
                    this.rigidbody.mass += growth;
                    Scale = this.transform.localScale;
                    Scale.y += growth;
                    this.transform.localScale = Scale;
                }

                found = true;
                break;

            case 333:
                growth = DNAReader(1);
                if(entity.RequestResources(growth*2,growth))
                {
                    this.rigidbody.mass += growth;
                    Scale = this.transform.localScale;
                    Scale.z += growth;
                    this.transform.localScale = Scale;
                }

                found = true;
                break;

            case 334:
                int growthx = DNAReader(1);
                int growthy = DNAReader(1);
                int growthz = DNAReader(1);

                growth = growthz*growthy*growthx;
                this.rigidbody.mass += growth;

                if(entity.RequestResources(growth*2,growth))
                {

                    Scale = transform.localScale;


                    Scale.x += growthx; 
                    Scale.y += growthy; 
                    Scale.z += growthz; 

                    transform.localScale = Scale;
                }

                found = true;
                break;


            case 335:
                Scale = this.transform.localScale;

                growth = DNAReader(1);
                Scale.x = growth; 
                Scale.y = growth; 
                Scale.z = growth; 
                this.transform.localScale = Scale;

                found = true;
                break;

            case 411:
                //Create Body part
                int shape = DNAReader(1);
                int type = DNAReader(1);

                int px = DNAReader(1);
                int py = DNAReader(1);
                int pz = DNAReader(1);

                int rx = DNAReader(1);
                int ry = DNAReader(1);
                int rz = DNAReader(1);

                int bf = DNAReader(1);
                int bt = DNAReader(1);
                break;

            case -1:
                this.Growing = false;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your objects are too massive or being pulled downwards or both

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the collider of your object to make sure it is fitting in your object entirely.

Comment: I only use primitive shapes and the only modification I do to them is scale, rotate and transform (sorry if I'm using the wrong language). Whit being said would I still need to check the collider?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the item is being pulled downward too quickly and embeds itself or passes through the terrain entirely. Since the terrain is essentially 2d it doesn't take as much speed as you'd think to pass through it.

What shape is the bottom of the collider? I recognize the other issues, but I haven't seen the "vibration" effect you are describing before.

Since you mentioned scaling, be aware that scaling an object can wreak havoc on the engine in a number of ways, but if we are only talking about a main game object being scaled (as opposed to hundreds of objects or the terrain itself) that probably isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible reasons that collision behaves weird:

1. Object is moving too quickly. This is probably the reason why your object is sometimes passing through the terrain.
2. You are modifying its transform in `Update` instead of `FixedUpdate`. This can cause the object vibration. [Here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/help-with-vibrating-objects-upon-collision.540094/) it is explained why you should use fixed update.
3. Your collider isn't fitting entire object.